# windows snip tool, capture scrolling page

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, screen-capture, snipping

I'm trying to capture a scrolling page using windows 8 snip tool. I've tried the window capture option but it just captures the visible part of the page, not the part that would be revealed by scrolling.
any ideas?

Comment: yes a web page or any scrolling window. I do not prefer specifying the application whose window I'm trying to capture since I'm looking for a general solution. I know there are browser plugins that capture whole page but I'm looking for a way to do it  using Windows snipping tool.

Answer (score 17):

Google Chrome includes a built-in screenshot tool, but it's a bit hidden. You'll first enter two sets of keyboard shortcuts, then enter a command to capture a full-page screenshot of any web page. Start by using the shortcut pairs below—enter the first shortcut, followed by the second—depending on your operating system:

On Mac
1. Alt + Command + I
2. Command + Shift + P

On Windows/Linux/Chrome OS
1. Ctrl + Shift + I
2. Ctrl + Shift + P

These keyboard shortcuts will open Chrome's developer menu. Just type "screenshot" and you'll see the option appear to "capture full size screenshot." Simply select this and Chrome will automatically save a full-page screenshot to your Downloads folder!

Comment: This only captures the current view, it does not scroll it and capture the entire page.

Answer (score 8):

There is a third party tool name **SnagIt**, It can scroll and capture as well.

There is also another free tool **PicPick** you can download it from: https://picpick.app

Comment: The question is specifically about windows snip tool

Comment: The "scrolling window" capture is quite awesome.

Comment: Even though it's a third party tool, this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, this is not possible, not with Windows Snipping tool!